# Flutter app becomes much slower by just one widget

Tags: dart, flutter

So in my app I have a simple rating feature and in order to achieve this I've built a simple star widget which takes a 'fill' parameter 0.0-1.0 and the Rating widget uses a row of five stars counting the appropriate fill. The problem is that for some unexplainable reason the list (cuz it appears on a list) becomes so much slower when that specific widget is removed. Here's the code for he star:

```
class Star extends StatelessWidget {
  final double fill;
  final double scale;
  Star({@required this.fill, this.scale = 1.0}):
    assert(fill<=1.0 && fill >=0.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 2.5*scale,
      ),
      child: new Material(
        elevation: 2.0,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
        child: new Container(
          height: 14.0*scale,
          width: 14.0*scale,
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: this.fill * 14.0*scale,
              ),
              new Center(
                child: new Material(
                  elevation: 3.0,
                  color: new Color(0x00000000),
                  child: new Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    size: 12.0*scale,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the full rating widget:

```
class Rating extends StatelessWidget {
  final double rating;
  final double scale;

  Rating({
    @required this.rating,
    this.scale = 1.0,
  })
      : assert(rating <= 5 && rating >= 0);

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Star> stars = new List.generate(5, (index) {
      return new Star(
        fill: _getFill(index),
        scale: scale,
      );
    });

    return new Row(
      children: stars,
    );
  }

  int _getStarsNeeded() {
    double r = rating;
    if (r <= 0)
      return 0;
    else if (r > 0 && r <= 1)
      return 1;
    else if (r > 1 && r <= 2)
      return 2;
    else if (r > 2 && r <= 3)
      return 3;
    else if (r > 3 && r <= 4)
      return 4;
    else
      return 5;
  }

  double _getEndingStarFill() {
    return (rating + 1 - _getStarsNeeded());
  }

  double _getFill(index) {
    int neededStars = _getStarsNeeded();
    if (index < neededStars - 1) {
      return 1.0;
    } else if (index == neededStars - 1) {
      return _getEndingStarFill();
    } else
      return 0.0;
  }
}
```

I know this is not the best way to find the fill but that can't be the case here. And yet looks so simple to make things heavy.

Comment: Try the profiling feature in Observatory to get an idea where it does so much work that it becomes slow. I haven't seen anything in your code that would cause any measurabl CPU usage at all.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try the Observatory tomorrow but still it's weird :/

Comment: The debug version of builds are much slower than the production ones. Try building for production and see if that's faster.

Comment: Nah it's a release mode but I still haven't understood why this happens :/ And yet the snippet I've provided is not my final one. I was also planning to animate the rating from 0 but until I get to fix this, I'll drop the idea.